# Verilog: one clock cycle delay using register

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to delay two signals. I wrote a register to do that and instantiated it but a strange thing happens. Delaying "state" signal seems to work, but delaying "nb_bits" signal doesn't.

Here's my code for the register:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module register(
    input CLK,
    input clr,
    input en,
    input [7:0] in,
    output [7:0] out
    );

    reg [7:0] temp;

    always @ (posedge CLK or posedge clr) begin
        if (clr) begin
            temp <= 8'b00010000;
        end
        else if (en) begin
            temp <= in;
        end
        else begin
            temp <= temp;
        end
    end

    assign out = temp;

endmodule
```

And that's ma instantiation:

```
wire [3:0] nbb;
nb_bits_register nb_bits_reg(
    .CLK(CLK),
    .clr(clr),
    .en(en),
    .in(nb_bits),
    .out(nbb)
);

wire [7:0] stt;
register state_reg(
    .CLK(CLK),
    .clr(clr),
    .en(en),
    .in(state),
    .out(stt)
);
```

nb_bits_register module is analogical; I didn't want to parametrize before solving this problem.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module nb_bits_register(
    input CLK,
    input clr,
    input en,
    input [3:0] in,
    output [3:0] out
    );

    reg [3:0] temp;

    always @ (posedge CLK or posedge clr) begin
        if (clr) begin
            temp <= 4'b0000;
        end
        else if (en) begin
            temp <= in;
        end
        else begin
            temp <= temp;
        end
    end

    assign out = temp;

endmodule
```

And here's a simulation:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWVvj.png)

And testbench:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module state_machine_tb();

    reg CLK, clr, en;
    reg [7:0] symbol;
    reg [3:0] nb_bits;
    wire [7:0] state;

    initial begin
        CLK <= 1;
        clr <= 0;
        en <= 0;
        symbol <= 8'b00110010;
        nb_bits <= 1;
        #10

        clr <= 1;
        en <= 1;
        #10

        clr <= 0;
        symbol <= 8'b00110001;
        nb_bits <= 1;
        #10

        symbol <= 8'b00110010;
        nb_bits <= 2;
        #10

        symbol <= 8'b00110001;
        nb_bits <= 1;
        #10

        symbol <= 8'b00110001;
        nb_bits <= 1;
        #10

        symbol <= 8'b00110000;
        nb_bits <= 3;
        #10

        $finish;
    end

    always begin
        #5 CLK <= ~CLK;
    end

    state_machine state_machine_inst(
        .CLK(CLK),
        .clr(clr),
        .en(en),
        .symbol(symbol),
        .nb_bits(nb_bits),
        .state(state)
    );

endmodule
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does seem like a rase condition in the scheduler. By definition from the Verilog LRM, the order of evaluating procedural blocks (always blocks and initial blocks) is indeterminate. You might notice a pattern with a particular simulator and version, but that patter can change when changing the simulator or changing the version of the same simulator.

- Use blocking assignment with your clock (ex: `always #5 CLK = ~CLK;`). With will guarantee the `CLK` will be updated before other stimulus.
- In the test bench, change all the `#10` to `@(posedge CLK)`. The timing will be the same, however it guarantees `CLK` was updated before evaluating the new values `symbol` and other stimulus.

---

FYI: If you change `output [7:0] out` to `output reg [7:0] out` you can assign `out` directly in your always block, removing the need for `temp`. This doesn't change anything functionally; just fewer variables and lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a race condition: your changes of `nb_bits` coincide with positive edges of `CLK`, so there's an ambiguity resolved by the simulator in this way:

- change `nb_bits` (from 1 to 2, etc.)
- change `CLK` from 0 to 1
- execute in `nb_bits_register`: `if (en) temp <= in; ... assign out = temp;`

As the result, `out = in` in `nb_bits_register`.

A solution is to avoid this coincidence, e.g. by changing the first `#10` in the testbench to `#11`.